# Access violation on reading location 0x33313032. when build the project under x86 platform the ame works fine under 64bit platform

Tags: .net, access-violation

Im getting this error when i run my dualcore project with build set to x86 platform on vs2010

Unhandled exception at 0x6711b1a5 in dualcore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x33313032.

and the application breaks.

when checked on windows event logger it specified the following "Application error" and the "runtime error":

## Application error :

Faulting application name: Dual OS.exe, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x51b742ba
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.30319.460, time stamp: 0x4db13576
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0007b1a5
Faulting process id: 0x13b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce68c896a83d38
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Samsung\Dual OS\Dual OS.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
Report Id: ed3658bb-d4bb-11e2-a5e2-3860772fed6d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

## Runtime error:

Application: dualcore.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at ._wWinMainCRTStartup()

The same project works fine when built under x64 bit.

I need the same 32bit also

kindly help me out to solve this!.

Comment: You seem quite confused, using the [.net] tag for a problem with a C++ program.  A crash like this is very, very common in a C or C++ program.  Use a debugger.  Ask help from a coworker.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to provide a meaningful answer. We need to see the code where the error might be, so that we can analyze it and determine where the error actually is. And the information that is provided is a bit puzzling. What is "dualcore.exe"? What's "Dual OS.exe"? How are they related to each other? Can you debug your code? When you debug it, can you break at the point where error occurs and see for yourself what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Number 0x33313032 is very suspicious. Those are actually letters "3" "1" "0" "2". Somewhere in your code you have those letters in the memory, and the code thinks that that part of memory is some pointer instead of those four letters, and is trying to reach where the pointer points, which is 0x33313032.

Comment: no i dont have any such letters being mentioned in my code. Can you be more clear.